# Проблема с правильным выводом

Tags: python

> **Задача**

Напишите функцию, которая принимает неотрицательное целое число (секунды) в качестве входных данных и возвращает время в удобочитаемом формате (HH:MM:SS)

HH= часы, дополненные до 2 цифр, диапазон: 00–99

MM= минуты, дополненные до 2 цифр, диапазон: 00–59

SS= секунды, дополненные до 2 цифр, диапазон: 00–59

Максимальное время никогда не превышает 359999 (99:59:59)

**Примеры вывода**

> `00:00:00`
> `00:00:05`
> `00:01:00`
> `23:59:59`
> `99:59:59`

Вот мой код:

```
def make_readable(seconds):
    # Do something
    x = ''
    p_1 = seconds // 3600
    p_2 = (seconds - (seconds // 3600)* 3600) // 60
    p_3 = seconds  - (p_1 * 3600 + p_2 * 60)
    x += str(p_1) + ':' + str(p_2) + ':' + str(p_3)   
return x
```

Проблема заключается в том, что сам код и вывод правильны (считает всё отлично, проверил множество раз), но вот формат вывода должен быть, например: `00:12:02` или `03:04:29`.

А мой вывод `0:12:2`, `3:4:29`.

Comment: Не обращайте внимание на диапазон. Сайт не будет превышать эти значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй форматирование: (f-строки)

```
return f'{p_1:02d}:{p_2:02d}:{p_3:02d}'
```